# how to decode arabic json data from facebook in android?

Tags: android, json, parsing, arabic

I develope some app retrieve posts from facebook by json in arabic .. but all data in arabic are encoded with unknown approach for me like that in title and content :

https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=103622369714881&format=json

```
"title": " #&#x631;&#x635;&#x62f; | &#x628;&#x64a;&#x627;&#x646; &#x647;&#x627;&#x645;: &#x62a;&#x639;&#x644;&#x646; &#x634;&#x628;&#x643;&#x629; &#x631;&#x635;&#x62f; &#x627;&#x644;&#x625;&#x62e;&#x628;&#x627;&#x631;&#x64a;&#x629; &#x639;&#x646; &#x642;&#x627;&#x626;&#x645;&#x629; &#x628;&#x627;&#x644;&#x645;&#x648;&#x627;&#x642;&#x639; &#x648;&#x627;&#x644;&#x62d;&#x633;&#x627;&#x628;&#x627;&#x62a; &#x627;&#x644;&#x631;&#x633;&#x645;&#x64a;&#x629; &#x627;&#x644;&#x62a;...",
         "id": "392844a43334c611060f3401300948dc",
         "alternate": "https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/photo.php?fbid=597021777041602&set=a.280183138725469.58204.103622369714881&type=1",
         "categories": [

         ],
         "published": "2013-09-05T03:39:59+01:00",
         "updated": "2013-09-05T03:39:59+01:00",
         "author": {
            "name": "R.N.N | &#x634;&#x628;&#x643;&#x629; &#x631;&#x635;&#x62f;"
         },
         "verb": "",
         "target": "",
         "objects": "",
         "comments": "",
         "likes": "",
         "content": "\u202b#\u0631\u0635\u062f | \u0628\u064a\u0627\u0646 \u0647\u0627\u0645: \u062a\u0639\u0644\u0646 \u0634\u0628\u0643\u0629 \u0631\u0635\u062f \u0627\u0644\u0625\u062e\u0628\u0627\u0631\u064a\u0629 \u0639\u0646 \u0642\u0627\u0626\u0645\u0629 \u0628\u0627\u0644\u0645\u0648\u0627\u0642\u0639 \u0648\u0627\u0644\u062d\u0633\u0627\u0628\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u0631\u0633\u0645\u064a\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u062a\u064a \u062a\u0645\u062b\u0644\u0647\u0627 \u0648\u0647\u064a \u0643\u0627\u0644\u062a\u0627\u0644\u064a:\u003Cbr \/> \u003Cbr \/> \u0645\u0648\u0642\u0639 \u0631\u0635\u062f : \u202c\u003Ca href=\"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/l.php?u=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fwww.rassd.com&amp;h=9AQGoR_rF&amp;s=1\" rel=\"nofollow nofollow\" target=\"_blank\" onmouseover=\"LinkshimAsyncLink.swap(this, &quot;http:\\\/\\\/www.rassd.com\\\/&quot;);\" onclick=\"LinkshimAsyncLink.referrer_log(this, &quot;http:\\\/\\\/www.rassd.com\\\/&quot;, &quot;https:\\\/\\\/www.facebook.com\\\/si\\\/ajax\\\/l\\\/render_linkshim_log\\\/?u=http\\u00253A\\u00252F\\u00252Fwww.rassd.com&amp;h=9AQGoR_rF&amp;s=1&quot;);\">www.rassd.com\u003C\/a>\u202b\u003Cbr \/> \u003Cbr \/> \u0641\u064a\u0633 \u0628\u0648\u0643: \u202c\u003Ca href=\"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/RNN.NEWS\" rel=\"nofollow\">www.facebook.com\/RNN.NEWS\u003C\/a>\u202b\u003Cbr \/> \u003Cbr \/> \u062a\u0648\u064a\u062a\u0631 : \u202c\u003Ca href=\"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/l.php?u=https\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Ftwitter.com\u00252FRassd_News&amp;h=BAQEvhv1v&amp;s=1\" rel=\"nofollow nofollow\" target=\"_blank\" onmouseover=\"LinkshimAsyncLink.swap(this, &quot;https:\\\/\\\/twitter.com\\\/Rassd_News&quot;);\" onclick=\"LinkshimAsyncLink.referrer_log(this, &quot;https:\\\/\\\/twitter.com\\\/Rassd_News&quot;, &quot;https:\\\/\\\/www.facebook.com\\\/si\\\/ajax\\\/l\\\/render_linkshim_log\\\/?u=https\\u00253A\\u00252F\\u00252Ftwitter.com\\u00252FRassd_News&amp;h=BAQEvhv1v&amp;s=1&quot;);\">https:\/\/twitter.com\/Rassd_News\u003C\/a>\u202b\u003Cbr \/> \u003Cbr \/> \u064a\u0648\u062a\u064a\u0648\u0628 : \u202c\u003Ca href=\"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/l.php?u=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fwww.youtube.com\u00252Fuser\u00252Frnnnews1&amp;h=qAQEC53Ud&amp;s=1\" rel=\"nofollow nofollow\" target=\"_blank\" onmouseover=\"LinkshimAsyncLink.swap(this, &quot;http:\\\/\\\/www.youtube.com\\\/user\\\/rnnnews1&quot;);\" onclick=\"LinkshimAsyncLink.referrer_log(this, &quot;http:\\\/\\\/www.youtube.com\\\/user\\\/rnnnews1&quot;, &quot;https:\\\/\\\/www.facebook.com\\\/si\\\/ajax\\\/l\\\/render_linkshim_log\\\/?u=http\\u00253A\\u00252F\\u00252Fwww.youtube.com\\u00252Fuser\\u00252Frnnnews1&amp;h=qAQEC53Ud&amp;s=1&quot;);\">www.youtube.com\/user\/rnnnews1\u003C\/a>\u202b \u003Cbr \/> \u003Cbr \/> \u0628\u0627\u0644\u0625\u0636\u0627\u0641\u0629 \u0625\u0644\u064a \u0635\u0641\u062d\u0627\u062a\u0647\u0627 \u0627\u0644\u0646\u0627\u0637\u0642\u0629 \u0628\u0627\u0644\u0644\u063a\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u0645\u062e\u062a\u0644\u0641\u0629 \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0635\u0641\u062d\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u0645\u062a\u062e\u0635\u0635\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0636\u0627\u0641\u0629 \u0641\u064a \u0642\u0627\u0626\u0645\u0629 \u0625\u0639\u062c\u0627\u0628\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u0635\u0641\u062d\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0631\u0633\u0645\u064a\u0629 \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u0641\u064a\u0633 \u0628\u0648\u0643.\u003Cbr \/> \u003Cbr \/> \u0648\u0623\u064a \u0631\u0648\u0627\u0628\u0637 \u063a\u064a\u0631 \u0630\u0644\u0643 \u0647\u064a \u0625\u062d\u062a\u064a\u0627\u0644 \u0648\u0627\u0633\u062a\u063a\u0644\u0627\u0644 \u0644\u0627\u0646\u062a\u0634\u0627\u0631 \u0627\u0633\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0634\u0628\u0643\u0629 \u0648\u0634\u0647\u0631\u062a\u0647\u0627 \u0648\u0633\u0631\u0642\u0629 \u0644\u0645\u0644\u0643\u064a\u062a\u0647\u0627 \u0627\u0644\u0641\u0643\u0631\u064a\u0629 \u0648\u0639\u0644\u0627\u0645\u062a\u0647\u0627 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0633\u062c\u0644\u0629 \u0645\u062d\u0644\u064a\u0627\u064b \u0648\u062f\u0648\u0644\u064a\u0627\u064b.\u003Cbr \/> \u003Cbr \/> \u0631\u0635\u062f .. \u0625\u0639\u0644\u0627\u0645 \u064a\u0635\u0646\u0639\u0647 \u0627\u0644\u062c\u0645\u0647\u0648\u0631\u202c\u003Cbr\/>\u003Cbr\/>\u003Ca href=\"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/photo.php?fbid=597021777041602&amp;set=a.280183138725469.58204.103622369714881&amp;type=1&amp;relevant_count=1\" id=\"\" title=\"\" target=\"\" onclick=\"\" style=\"\">\u003Cimg class=\"img\" src=\"https:\/\/fbcdn-photos-a-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-ash4\/264524_597021777041602_1616125455_s.jpg\" alt=\"\" \/>\u003C\/a>"
      },
```

I used UTF-8 in parsing but it doesn't change anything -- jist decode this code like that

```
\u0635\u0641\u062d\u0627\u062a\u0647\u0627 \u0627\u0644\u0646\u0627\u0637\u0642\u0629 \u0628\u0627\u0644\u0644\u063a\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u06
```

but this code wasn't decoded

```
#&#x631;&#x635;&#x62f; | &#x628;&#x64a;&#x627;&#x646; &#x647;&#x627;&#x645;: &#x62a;&#x639;&#x644;&#x646; &#x634;&#x628;&#x643;&#x629; &#x631;&#x635;&#x62f; &#x627;&#x644;&#x625;&#x62e;&#x628;&#x627;&#x631;&#x64a;&#x629; &#x639;&#x646; &#x642;&#x627;&#x626;&#x645;&#x629;
```

Now how can i decode that code and also decode html tags ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The values are given as [HTML entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp), which means that a string like this

> ```
>   &#x628;&#x64a;&#x627;&#x646;
> ```

will appear like this

بيان

when used directly in an HTML document. It's just like using `&nbsp;` to create an extra space within a `<p>` block, for example.

Comment: thank you .. but how can i solve it ina android and how can i decode it ??

Comment: check out [`Html.fromHtml()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String)). You can pass your HTML entity string as the argument

Answer (score -1):

i made this function and it worked :)
this for posting with curl

```
   public function decaodeingthis($url,$postData){


             $ch = curl_init();

             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

                  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
             $output = curl_exec($ch); return  $output;
             curl_close($ch);


            }
```

and this for decoding :

```
$arraq = array('html_input'=>'encoded text here','submit'=>'Decode text','bAjax'=>1);
   $title = self::decaodeingthis('http://www.web2generators.com/html/entities',$arraq);
```

Comment: You shouldn't make a request to a third party web-site such as http://www.web2generators.com/html/entities -- 1. This will be slower as it needs time to place a request -- 2. You do not have approval from the Web-site and it might change the URL at some point which will break your app -- 3. You already have access to those king of methods: see @jbr3zy's comment.